# Quesiton about functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, differential

I'm embarrassed asking this question. I took a long break. 
main question is :
cartesian coordinate system in $R^n$ space is shown as $(x_1,x_2 ...x_n)$. Show that for $1\le i\le n$  each $x_i:R^n\mapsto R$ function have partial derivatives with respect to its $k.$ variable and             $$for \quad   1\le k\le n \quad \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k}(p)=\delta_{ik}  $$

Answer in the book was: for $1\le i \le n$

[image]for $1\le i,j \le n$ let $i\neq j$

[image]

I dont understand  why is $x_i(p_1,p_2...p_{i-1},p_i+s, p_{i+1, ...p_n})=[p_i+s]$ at 1* . and isn't 2* wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite trivial.  Let $\{e_1,\dots e_n\}$ then $\{x_1,\dots x_n\}$ is the dual basis. So you understand $1^*$, don't you?  $2^*$ is  a typo since $p_i-p_i=0$.